# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge exception while unit testing presenter class

Tags: java, gwt, junit

I am trying to test one of my presenter class in GWT application.
Following is my constructor of presenter class which is to be tested.

```
@Inject
public MyPresenter(MyView view, MyService myService) {
    super(view, myService);
    view.setDelegate(this);
}
```

Following is my setup() method of test class.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

mockMyView = Mockito.mock(MyWidget.class);
mockMyService = Mockito.mock(myService.class);

sut = new MyPresenter(mockMyView, mockMyService);
```

I got following exception while executing above setup() method.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.<clinit>(UIObject.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
    at com...MyPresenterTest.setUp(MyPresenterTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.client.GWTBridge
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
```

Does it mean we can't mock GWT widget class as other class?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which GWT version are you using? Is either gwt-dev or gwt-servlet in your test classpath?

Comment: I am using gwt version 2.5.1. How to check test classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock MyView, not MyWidget. MyWidget extends from Widget (and UIObject), and as you discovered you cannot mock widgets.

Well, actually, you can, using [GWT Mockito](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito), but it looks like you don't need to in your case, as you already have a MyView abstraction (that's an interface implemented by MyWidget, right?)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, for your perfect suggestion.